# Read Write Variable to/from file in c++

Tags: c++, file, save

I'm trying to make my c++ program to write then read a variable from file, but no success.. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int f;
int main()

{
    ifstream in("variabila.txt");


  ofstream fout;
fout.open("variabila.txt");

fout<<f<<endl;
fout.close();

cout << f << endl;
cin >> f;
in >> f;
 cout << f << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: I think the order of operation matters. And what's `cin >> f;` doing there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open the file for reading after you close the file for writing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
const int f = 123;

int main()
{
 {
  ofstream fout("variabila.txt");
  fout<<f<<endl;
 }

 {
  ifstream in("variabila.txt");
  int g;
  in >> g;
  cout << g << endl;
 }

 return 0;
}
```